# How to make object move in js?

Tags: javascript, 2d-games

I'm trying to learn object oriented programming in javascript so I try to make a simple game. I would like to make a character that moves. There is the code in js:

```
  function move(event)
    {
var k=event.keyCode; 

var chr = {

    updown : function (){
            var y=0;
            if (k==38) 
                {--y;
            }else if (k==40)
                 {++y;}
            return y; 
        },

    leftright : function (){
        var x=0;
        if (k==37) 
            {--x;
        }else if (k==39) 
            {++x;}
        return x; 
            }


    };

    chrId.style.top = (chr.updown())+"px";
    chrId.style.left = (chr.leftright())+"px";

}
```

html:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jumpOPP.css">
<script src="jumpOPP.js"></script>
</head>

<body  onkeydown="move(event)">
<img id="chrId" src="TrackingDot.png" >


</body>
</html>
```

and CSS:

```
#chrId {
    position: relative;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
}
```

When I press and hold up, down, left, right the dot moves only for a one place. How to make it moving whole time I' m holding some key. I have made it without var char to move. I used function move(event) and then a switch, cases 38, 37, 39 and 40 and then it change style.top but I can't make it in one object.

Is it possible to make a object chr = {objekt movement, life, power...} and then a object ground = {some code that stops the chr} and other interacting objects ? Can somebody recomend a good tutorial for that? :) 
Thank you

Comment: function `move()` must call itself again and again with a setTimeout, so it will be targeted to 60fps, and on keyUp, you must kill this repetition of `move()` either via a flag variable or some other way (clearTimeout)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here working jsfiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/t5ya4j26/

You error in define local variables in scopes that always will equal to 0. So for fix that, you must get current `left` and `top` of element, not define `x = 0` and `y = 0`.

```
function move(event) {
var k = event.keyCode,
    chrId = document.getElementById('test'),
    chr = {
        updown: function () {
            var y = parseInt(getComputedStyle(chrId).top);
            if (k == 38) {
                --y;
            } else if (k == 40) {
                ++y;
            }

            return y;
        },

        leftright: function () {
            var x = parseInt(getComputedStyle(chrId).left);
            if (k == 37) {
                --x;
            } else if (k == 39) {
                ++x;
            }

            return x;
        }
    };

chrId.style.top = (chr.updown()) + "px";
chrId.style.left = (chr.leftright()) + "px";
}

document.addEventListener('keydown', move);
```

Comment: Thank you! Can you recommend me a good tutorial or a book to learn OOP?

Comment: @user2980958 you just starts learning JavaScript, so will be helpful almost all books, blogs, etc... Just type in search "JavaScript book". Also you can find answer in other SO question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11246/best-resources-to-learn-javascript

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend that you use the `<canvas>` element for stuff like this. But use `window.setInterval(function, milliseconds)` to have it repeatedly run your 'move' function and then when a key is released, `window.onkeyup` clear that interval.

```
clearInterval(intervalName);
```

This requires you to make a new event listener. Instead of having your event listener in body, use:

```
window.onkeydown = function(event) {
    var k = event.which || event.keyCode;  // This adds compatibilty across all browsers
    // Code to be run
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know that you are looking for the function in an object, but moving an element is really quick and easy with this, I just made this today for my beginners game:

```
var change = (parseInt(chrId.style.left.replace('%',''),10) + 3).toString() + "%"
    chrId.style.left = change
```

The % signs can be replaced with 'px' if you are using pixel values to move, and the ' + 3 ' is how many pixels or percentage points you want your element to move per execution.

The same can be done for up by changing the 'left' to 'top'.

Answer (score 0):

My code might not be to your liking, but I'm just trying to demonstrate how I work around this problem, I am positively sure that there are hundreds of better ways, but this one seems to save me a lot of trouble for a lot of other stuff.

Hope I was able understand the question and help though, sorry if I couldn't :)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<meta charset = "utf-8">
<title> MOVEMENT </title>
</head>

<body>
<script type = "text/javascript">
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// VARIABLES are set here so they're GLOBAL (everything may access them)
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

let lock_left = true
let lock_top = true
let lock_right = true
let lock_bottom = true

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

let html; let htmls
let body; let bodys
let avatar; let avatars

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

let avatar_x = 0
let avatar_y = 0

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// EVERY map will be an object, and every object needs a CREATE function that
// will happen only ONCE and an UPDATE function that will repeat itself
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

const map_main =
{
    create: function()
        {
            html = document.querySelector( "html" ); htmls = html.style
            body = document.querySelector( "body" ); bodys = body.style
        },

    //--------------------------------------------------------------------------

    update: function()
        {
            htmls.width = "100%"
            htmls.height = "100%"
            htmls.margin = "0"

            bodys.width = "100%"
            bodys.height = "100%"
            bodys.margin = "0"

            bodys.backgroundColor = "rgb( 120, 200, 80 )"
        },
}

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

const map_avatar =
{
    create: function()
        {
            avatar = document.createElement( "div" ); avatars = avatar.style
            body.appendChild( avatar )
        },

    //--------------------------------------------------------------------------

    update: function()
        {
            avatars.width = "64px"
            avatars.height = "64px"
            avatars.backgroundColor = "rgb( 200, 80, 120 )"

            avatars.position = "absolute"
            avatars.top = avatar_y + "px"
            avatars.left = avatar_x + "px"
        },
}

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// BELOW are the 2 main gears of the engine
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

// EVERY code that only needs to happen once is called here
const master_create = function()
{
    map_main.create()
    map_avatar.create()
}

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

// EVERYTHING that needs constant updates is called here
const master_update = function()
{
    map_main.update()
    map_avatar.update()

    movement()

    window.requestAnimationFrame( master_update )
}

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// BELOW is showing how the keyboard affects the locks
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

const press = function( pressed )
{
    if( pressed.keyCode === 37 || pressed.keyCode === 69 ) lock_left = false
    if( pressed.keyCode === 38 || pressed.keyCode === 82 ) lock_top = false
    if( pressed.keyCode === 39 || pressed.keyCode === 70 ) lock_right = false
    if( pressed.keyCode === 40 || pressed.keyCode === 68 ) lock_bottom = false
}

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

const release = function( released )
{
    if( released.keyCode === 37 || released.keyCode === 69 ) lock_left = true
    if( released.keyCode === 38 || released.keyCode === 82 ) lock_top = true
    if( released.keyCode === 39 || released.keyCode === 70 ) lock_right = true
    if( released.keyCode === 40 || released.keyCode === 68 ) lock_bottom = true
}

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// BELOW will check the LOCKS and use them to change AVATAR_X and AVATAR_Y
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

const movement = function()
{
    if( lock_left === false ) avatar_x -= 10
    if( lock_top === false ) avatar_y -= 10
    if( lock_right === false ) avatar_x += 10
    if( lock_bottom === false ) avatar_y += 10
}

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// BELOW we call the 2 gears and everything will work
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

master_create() // will be called only ONCE
master_update() // will repeat forever due to "window.requestAnimationFrame()"

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// LISTENERS should go after the engine starts rolling
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

body.addEventListener( "keydown", press, false )
body.addEventListener( "keyup", release, false )

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
</script>
</body>

</html>
```