# Moving a paragraph from left edge of a div to right edge in ES6 (text should be deleted and reappear)

Tags: javascript, html

Sorry if I misphrase anything, not sure how to phrase the need I'm having.

Say I have a paragraph inside a div:

```
<div style="width: 50px">
    <p>Hi</p>
</div>
```

1. I want to move the paragraph (which covers 0-2px), up until the 50px.
2. When it reaches 49/50, 1 letter will be gone.
3. When it reaches 50/50, all 2 letters be gone, and the same behavior will start again, from scratch...

To clarify: I mean to create these "old school" moving text bars, in which a text starts in the right edge of the bar, and moves pixel after pixel, in some speed, to the left edge, disappears, and again the same pattern.

I didn't find any code for "moving a text" (surly not in ES6) [[1]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44617545/moving-an-element-in-js), [[2]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25352760/how-to-make-object-move-in-js). Most of what I found is in Jquery, like [this article](http://download.remysharp.com/marquee.html), but I desire an ES6 vanilla solution.

Comment: Can you provide any animation/videos about what you want to achieve?

Comment: post some code snippet of what you tried in order to help you

Comment: I didn't try anything. I don't know how to move html objects on the screen with JS.

Comment: Yes @AngYC you can see an example to the moving text here (http://walla.co.il), directly in the home page from a PC, you could see moving text "מבזקים".

Comment: You will want to do that with a CSS animation, not JS.

Comment: Do you mean marquee?

Comment: Yes I didn't know this is exactly the right term. I now understand there are several types of marquee.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can achieve that with CSS animations:

```css
div {
  overflow: hidden;
}

p {
  animation: marquee 2s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes marquee {
  from {transform: translateX(-100%); }
  to {transform: translateX(100%); }
}
```

```html
<div style="width: 50px">
    <p>Hi</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I updated an old Javascript solution on SO below:

```js
const marquees = [...document.querySelectorAll('.marquee')];
marquees.forEach((marquee) => {
  marquee.innerHTML = marquee.innerHTML + '&nbsp;'.repeat(5);
  marquee.i = 0;
  marquee.step = 3;
 marquee.width = (marquee.clientWidth + 1);
  marquee.style.position = '';
  marquee.innerHTML = `${marquee.innerHTML}&nbsp;`.repeat(10);
  marquee.addEventListener('mouseenter', () => marquee.step = 0, false);
  marquee.addEventListener('mouseleave', () => marquee.step = 3, false);
});

setInterval(move, 50);

function move() {
  marquees
  .forEach((marquee) => {
  marquee.style.marginLeft = `-${marquee.i}px`;;
  marquee.i = marquee.i < marquee.width ? marquee.i + marquee.step : 1;
  }); 
}
// Modified from StackOverflow answer by Stano:
// https://stackoverflow.com/questions/337330/javascript-marquee-to-replace-marquee-tags
```

```css
.marquee {
    background: #eee;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
    position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="marquee">Hey there!</div>
```

Hopefully this helps. Cheers!

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/LMulvey/v29r6uj7/)